# Setting UITableView editing in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just trying to perform a very simple system API call, setting a UITableView to **editing.**

However I have no idea what the compiler is complaining about:

```
let isEditing = self.tableView?.editing
self.tableView?.setEditing(!isEditing, animated: true)
```

Error Message:

> Optional type '_' cannot be used as a boolean; test for '!= nil' instead

Thankful for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just unwrap optional and use `!isEditing!`, but I believe this approach will be much safer:

```
if let isEditing = self.tableView?.editing {
   self.tableView?.setEditing(!isEditing, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `isEditing` variable type is Bool optional so apart true and false , it may have nil value as well and thats because of question mark used in `self.tableView?.editing`. To make it work you will need to force unwrap its value by using `!` in either `self.tableView!.editing` or `self.tableView?.setEditing(!isEditing!, animated: true)`.

Be aware that force unwrapping may be harmful and lead to runtime exceptions, so try avoiding it by using optional unwrapping

Answer (score 0):

The question mark next to tableView means that if the property tableView is nil then tableView?.editing must return nil. This results in an optional Bool for the statement `let isEditing = self.tableView?.editing`

You can fix this using an exclamation mark instead of a question mark (if you are sure 100% that tableView exists), or more cleaner

```
if let isEditing = self.tableView?.editing {
    //If isEditing exists, than self.tableView exists for sure! If it doesn't
    //the only possible reason is that tableView is nil so there is no point
    //to try to call setEditing on a nil object. If isEditing is nil, the if
    //condition will fail and you will not get in this scope.
    self.tableView!.setEditing(!isEditing, animated: true)
}
```